# Canvas transform on cloth simulation + image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, skew

I'm using the **verlet.js** plugin in order create a cloth simulation on canvas with a texture image.

The only thing (and the most important BTW) part that I haven't arrived is that I need skew the drawImage in order to make it fit the correct position.

**[jsfiddle with the progress](https://jsfiddle.net/adrianperez/2qy7pd2m/4/)**

```
//Drawing the rectangle
ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();

ctx.moveTo(cloth.particles[i1].pos.x, cloth.particles[i1].pos.y);
ctx.lineTo(cloth.particles[i1+1].pos.x, cloth.particles[i1+1].pos.y);
ctx.lineTo(cloth.particles[i2].pos.x, cloth.particles[i2].pos.y);
ctx.lineTo(cloth.particles[i2-1].pos.x, cloth.particles[i2-1].pos.y);
ctx.lineTo(cloth.particles[i1].pos.x, cloth.particles[i1].pos.y);

ctx.strokeStyle = "#fff";
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();

//Wrapping the image
ctx.save();
var off = cloth.particles[i2].pos.x - cloth.particles[i1].pos.x;

//THIS IS WHAT I TRY TO SOLVE TO FIT TO THE RECTANGLES
//ctx.transform(1,0.5,0,1,0,0);
ctx.drawImage(img, cloth.particles[i1].pos.x,cloth.particles[i1].pos.y, off, off, cloth.particles[i1].pos.x,cloth.particles[i1].pos.y, off ,off);
ctx.restore();
}
```

I have tried to adapt other cloth simulations but without success. Any clue where I could find some info to accomplish that?

Comment: I think you'll find that the cloth simulation works by dividing each original rectangle into 2 triangles -- not by skewing the original rectangle ;-)

Comment: Yes @markE, I also tried, but I was in the same problem, drawImage set a rectangle and I will need skew it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using skew (or rather shear) to fill tiles only works if the cell is a parallelogram, as 2D affine transforms only support this shape.

Here is one approach:

- Calculate angle of upper line
- Calculate angle of left line
- Calculate width and height of cell

In a parallelogram bottom line will equal upper line, and of course right line equals left line.

Then set these angles as skew arguments for the transform coupled with translate to the upper left corner.

Then just repeat for each cell.

## Example

```js
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function() {

  var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"),
      tile1 = [
        {x: 10, y: 10},    // upper left corner
        {x: 210, y: 50},   // upper right
        {x: 230, y: 150},  // bottom right
        {x: 30, y: 110}    // bottom left
      ],
      tile2 = [
        {x: 210, y: 50},
        {x: 410, y: 5},
        {x: 430, y: 105},
        {x: 230, y: 150}
      ];
  
  renderTile(this, tile1);
  renderTile(this, tile2);
  
  function renderTile(img, tile) {
    var dx, dy, a1, a2, w, h, i = 1;

    // reference shape (remove this section):
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    ctx.moveTo(tile[0].x, tile[0].y);
    while(i < 4) ctx.lineTo(tile[i].x, tile[i++].y);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#0c0";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.stroke();
    
    // calc horizontal angle 
    dx = tile[1].x - tile[0].x;     // horizontal diff.
    dy = tile[1].y - tile[0].y;     // vertical diff.
    a1 = Math.atan2(dy, dx);        // angle, note dy,dx order here
    w = dx|0;                       // width based on diff for x

    // calc vertical angle 
    dx = tile[3].x - tile[0].x;
    dy = tile[3].y - tile[0].y;
    a2 = Math.atan2(dx, dy);        // note dx,dy order here
    h = dy|0;
    
    // draw image to fit parallelogram
    ctx.setTransform(1, a1, a2, 1, tile[0].x, tile[0].y);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);
  }
};

img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/rUeQDjE.png";
```

```html
<canvas width=500 height=160/>
```

**Note:** if your cloth simulation produces other shapes than parallelograms (ie. quadrilaterals), which is very likely since this is a physics simulation, this approach won't work well. In that case you need different techniques which are more compute heavy. For this reason WebGL is a better fit. Just my two cents..

Comment: It looks great, I understand what you mean about the quadrilaterals, my math are not so heavy so I will try with your code, WebGL is undoubtedly a way to explore this, thanks both.